# What events can be passed to sforce.console.fireEvent?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, console

Where can we find available parameters for `sforce.console.fireEvent('XYZ');`? Is there any list available for standard methods?

I can see this call in a Visualforce Page:

```
sforce.console.fireEvent('RefreshAccount');
```

Where might this event be defined, or is it a standard event?

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_fireevent.htm?search_text=fireevent) doesn't offer much guidance here.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation [fireEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_fireevent.htm?search_text=fireevent) this method is used to fire a "**custom**" event. Then you can use [addEventListener](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_addeventlistener.htm?search_text=fireevent) to handle your "**custom**" event. Using this technique you can implement communication between several components.

Try to search for "addEventListener('RefreshAccount'" in your project and you should find the handler for it. The implementation can be in Static resources as well if your Visualforce pages includes some custom libraries.